# PrimeFaces schedule time not showing on week/day

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

PrimeFaces does not show the endtime of an event. In the PrimeFaces Schedule Demo it does.

[image]

**Methods for converting a date and add minutes to them:**

```
private ScheduleModel eventResourceAvailPerDay = new DefaultScheduleModel();
Date dateBeginConverted = DateUtil.minsToHours(minsBegin, dteBeginResourceAvailPerDay);
Date dateEndConverted = DateUtil.minsToHours(minsEnd, dteBeginResourceAvailPerDay);
DefaultScheduleEvent newOrResourceAvailPerDayEvent = new DefaultScheduleEvent(reason, dateBeginConverted, dateEndConverted);
eventResourceAvailPerDay.addEvent(newResourceEvent);
```

**minsToHours**

```
public static Date minsToHours(Integer mins, Date availDate) {
   int hours = (int) Math.floor(mins / 60);
   int minutes = mins - (hours * 60);
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(availDate);
   cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE), hours, minites);
   return cal.getTime();
}
```

**My HTML output:**

```
<div class="fc-event-time">9:00</div>
```

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5, JSF 2.0

**PrimeFaces standard code:**

```
public ScheduleController() {  
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();  
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Champions League Match", previousDay8Pm(), previousDay11Pm()));  
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Birthday Party", today1Pm(), today6Pm()));  
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Breakfast at Tiffanys", nextDay9Am(), nextDay11Am()));  
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Plant the new garden stuff", theDayAfter3Pm(), fourDaysLater3pm()));  
    }

private Calendar today() {  
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
        calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);  

        return calendar;  
    }  

private Date previousDay8Pm() {  
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();  
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);  
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);  
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);  

        return t.getTime();  
    }
```

**PrimeFaces HTML output:**

```
<div class="fc-event-time">9:00 - 11:00</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to supply more information, e.g. the xhtml and backing beans

Comment: @zargarf i've added some HTML output, but xhtml is the same as PF and shouldnt have much effect on the output